# Using Activity as Context in other file

Tags: android, android-context

Assume that there is method in an  file (inherites for Object) that need to use Resources.
Why I cannot to it like:

```
public void myMethod(){
    Activity activity = new Activity();
    activity.getResources();
    ..................................
}
```

But only:

```
public void myMethod(Context context){
    context.getResources();
    ...............................
}
```

As I know an Activity inherits from Context so why I cannot use the first method?

Comment: Because Without waiting or defining for `onCreate()` of Activity you can't access its Context. Which has override method for super Activity Class.

Comment: For more info just look at these two classes [Activity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) and [ContextThemeWrapper](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.java#ContextThemeWrapper)

Answer (score 1):

Because just constructing an activity doesn't assign a context to it.

Comment: The method is in external class